# Ignore hidden rows above active cells to compare active cells with the first corresponding visible cell above

Tags: vba, excel

**Summary(tl;dr):** I try to create code that wether or not rows are hidden, the code should compare only visible values. Example: Take i=Rownumber, X=Colum : If no rows are hidden the code should compare values of Xi with Xi-1. If rows i-1 and i-2 are hidden, the code should compare values of Xi with Xi-3. You do not know beforehand which rows are hidden. [Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O0ux-umyqtNTRsVm56dE11Y0U/view?usp=drivesdk)

**Long:** As a novice, I am running a bit in circles here. I searched extensively on this and other forums but I think it is a bit out of reach for now.
If someone could give me a hint in the right direction I would be much obliged:

**Goal :** Cleanup the layout while not taking into account hidden rows.

The effect is what a Pivot Table can easily do, but I have a shared workbook and users need to update certain cells, so Pivot table is out.

**Set-up:**

1. An External (Column E) can have several internals working for him
2. An Internal (Column F) can work for several Externals
3. Some rows will be hidden due to filtering.
4. Users can sort on: 
   The External employee, starting on row 5
   Or the Internal employee : here column F, starting on row 5

I try to write VBAcode so :

1. If sorted on External:

   **If** the Value of Cell Ei **=** Value **first Visible** Cell abover E i **then** 
   Cell Ei **=** font white

   **IF** the Value of Cell Ei **=** Value **first Visible** Cell E i-1 **AND** the Value of Cell Fi **=** Value **first Visible** Cell F i-1 **then** Cell Fi **=** font white
2. Same idea but sorted on the Internal person

**My Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

    'ignore hidden rows above active cells to compare active cells with the first corresponding visible cell above

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurRow As Long

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2016")

    'Find Last Row

    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'compare with first visible cell above

    i = 1

    For CurRow = 6 To LastRow

        If sht.Rows(CurRow - i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

            If Range("E" & CurRow) = Range("E" & CurRow - 1) Then Range("E" & CurRow).Font.Color = vbGreen
            If Range("E" & CurRow) = Range("E" & CurRow - 1) And Range("F" & CurRow) = Range("F" & CurRow - 1) Then Range("F" & i).Font.Color = vbGreen

        Else: i = i + 1

        End If

    Next CurRow

End Sub
```

**My Problems**

- Code works well for Column E, but not for Column F when no rows are hidden.
- Code does not take into account the hidden rows, the whole purpose of this exercise.
- Code doesn't react to changes in Sort / hidden rows.

Help?

**Edit:** I succeeded with Conditional Formatting and Aggregate sorted on External, but it breaks down a bit when sorted on Internal. Hence I am looking at VBA.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when no rows are hidden?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond. When no rows are hidden, the code should compare Ei with Ei-1 and Fi with Fi-1. For example : if rows i-1 and i-2 are hidden, the code should compare values of Ei with Ei-3 and Fi with Fi-3. Will try to upload an example this noon.